# Convert scala map to java map

Tags: scala, scala-java-interop

How can i do to convert scala map to java HashMap?

My scala map below:

```
val map = Map((KEY_CONDITION, keyCondition), (RANGE_CONDITION, rangeCondition))
```

My java code below:

```
method(HashMap<String, Object> hashmap){
//do something
}
```

Thanks

Comment: Downvoted as the internet is plentiful of [*using scala  collections in java*](https://www.google.com/search?q=using+scala+collections+in+java) answers, including stackoverflow (no prior research was shown)

Comment: Seconding the downvote, for the same reason

Answer (score 1):

There's a large variety of converters in `scala.collection.JavaConverters` with implicit conversions in `scala.collection.JavaConversions`.  Once you load these implicits you should be able to pass the scala Maps directly to the java methods as if they were Java Maps

Comment: Hi Andrew, Thank you! I'm not a scala guy and still puzzled, could you please give some example :)